# Ruby - Convert formatted date to timestamp

Tags: ruby, date, time, timestamp

I need to convert a date string to the Unix timestamp format.
The string I get from an API looks like:

```
2015-05-27T07:39:59Z
```

with `.tr()` i get:

```
2015-05-27 07:39:59
```

which is a pretty regular date format. Nonetheless, Ruby isn't able to convert it to Unix TS format. I tried `.to_time.to_i` but I keep getting `NoMethodError` Errors.

In PHP the function `strtotime()` just works perfectly for this.
Is there some similar method for Ruby?

Comment: Does this help? http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your date string is in RFC3339 format. You can parse it into a `DateTime` object, then convert it to `Time` and finally to a UNIX timestamp.

```
require 'date'

DateTime.rfc3339('2015-05-27T07:39:59Z')
#=> #<DateTime: 2015-05-27T07:39:59+00:00 ((2457170j,27599s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>

DateTime.rfc3339('2015-05-27T07:39:59Z').to_time
#=> 2015-05-27 09:39:59 +0200

DateTime.rfc3339('2015-05-27T07:39:59Z').to_time.to_i
#=> 1432712399
```

For a more general approach, you can use [`DateTime.parse`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-parse) instead of [`DateTime.rfc3339`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-rfc3339), but it is better to use the more specific method if you know the format, because it prevents errors due to ambiguities in the date string. If you have a custom format, you can use [`DateTime.strptime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime) to parse it

Answer (score 3):

In rails 4, you can use like - `string.to_datetime.to_i`

```
"Thu, 26 May 2016 11:46:31 +0000".to_datetime.to_i
```

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'time'

str = "2015-05-27T07:39:59Z"
Time.parse(str).to_i # => 1432712399
```

Or, using Rails:

```
str.to_time.to_i
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string.tr!('TO',' ')
Time.parse(string)
```

Try this one