# pure ruby: filtered csv dates by #select but now want to obtain another column based on those date ranges

Tags: ruby, csv

So basically I am trying to look up some information in a gigantic csv file via Ruby(note I don't want excel solutions), I have converted unix timestamps to proper Time objects and sorted them and filtered them via #select. I am trying to find information about the purchase_amt given this particular time range (which I denote by start_date, end_date).

Currently I only have an array of the times filtered via the huge csv, but how can I use my code to get the purchase_amt given in the csv?

```
Unix_time    purchase_amt
1352948920   12.40

require 'csv'
require 'date'

start_date = DateTime.rfc3339('2014-06-22T00:00:00Z').to_time.to_i
end_date = DateTime.rfc3339('2014-07-22T00:00:00Z').to_time.to_i

csv = CSV.parse('sample_data.csv', headers: true, encoding: 'ISO-8859-1')

csv.each do |row|
    if (row['created_at'] >= start_date && row['created_at'] <= end_date)
        final_arry<< row
    end
end

puts csv
```

Comment: I'm thinking i'd access the purchase_amt by csv['purchase_amt'] which is straight forward, but Im wondering how I then deal with this massive array and apply the filtering work I did before...

Comment: One solution could be to modify the column value(Unix_time) in csv on first iteration..so that every column has the date as per your requirement and then on second iteration you can check whether it falls under start_date or end_date..if yes then get the row['purchase_amt'].

Comment: can you clarify? maybe show me an example please?

Comment: You should be printing final_array instead of csv...also initialize final_array before looping over csv like this: final_array = []

Comment: @Abhinay ok I initialized the variable and also took your advice to concat row to final_array but im still getting no output in terminal :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a gigantic CSV, you should use [`CSV.foreach`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-foreach).
It parses rows one after the other without loading the whole file in memory.

[`Range#cover?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F) also helps :

> Returns true if obj is between the begin and end of the range.

If you can, you should also do all the calculations inside the block, without returning a new array which could also become huge. It seems you do want a huge array though, so here goes :

```
require 'csv'

amounts = []

start_date = Time.new(2012, 1, 22)
end_date   = Time.new(2014, 7, 22)

search_range = (start_date.to_i..end_date.to_i)

CSV.foreach('data.csv', headers: true, col_sep: "\s", skip_blanks: true) do |row|
  next unless search_range.cover?(row['Unix_time'].to_i)
  amounts << row['purchase_amt'].to_f
end

p amounts
```

Comment: this is very close to what I want @EricDuminil but instead of summing the total amt i just want a list of each prices_amts that were sold between the search range. Does that make sense?

Comment: so basically instead of the Ln that has total amt I was hoping I could extract each individual amt in an array

Answer (score 1):

if I am not wrong you want to extract the records which falls under start_date..end_date range.
Now a better solution would be to just convert your start_date and end_date to unix timestamp like:

```
require 'date'

DateTime.rfc3339('2015-05-27T07:39:59Z')
#=> #<DateTime: 2015-05-27T07:39:59+00:00 ((2457170j,27599s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>

DateTime.rfc3339('2015-05-27T07:39:59Z').to_time
#=> 2015-05-27 09:39:59 +0200

DateTime.rfc3339('2015-05-27T07:39:59Z').to_time.to_i
#=> 1432712399
```

as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30480999/2545197

Now you should be able to run through the csv like:

```
csv = CSV.parse('sample_data.csv', :headers => true, :encoding => 'ISO-8859-1')
csv.each do |row|
  # apply your conditions here
  # something like...
  if row['date'] >=start_date && row['date']<=end_date
  # append it to some array
  # ary << row
  end
end
```

Let me know if this works for you

Comment: so that doesnt output anything... ill update my code above to show you whats going on

Comment: remember I want to get the purchase amt ultimately based off the condition of date selection